# VB.Net Hangman Game Multiple Rounds

Tags: vb.net

I need some help.

I'm currently creating a Hangman Game in VB.Net.

I'm at the stage where a random word is loaded in from a text file of 6 words, and you can click buttons to guess it. If you guess letters wrong, the frame is shown etc, if they're right, the letter shows in the word through labels.

The next bit, that I'm stuck on, is that multiple rounds are needed. I need there to be 3 turns of this hangman game, so, if you guess the word right you get 10 points, and if you fail, you get 0, **And then the game resets with your points and you can play again in Turn 2. Then again in Turn 3, and after Turn 3 finishes, the High Score Form is loaded.**

Comment: What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: Let's say you play the game, and get the word correct. I need to add 10 points (to a score variable) which is fine, but the main bit I'm stuck on is re-loading all controls and basically resetting the game, so that they can play it again. (But this time, it'll display Turn 2 in the label) I basically just need a way to reset the whole game so they can play again, but carry their score over.

Comment: Is this a windows form app or a web forms app?

Comment: Just a Windows Form app using Visual Studio 2012. There are multiple forms, a menu form, a play form, and a high score form. The code above is on the Play Form. I've created it all from scratch in VB.net

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable to hold the current round in your Module, at the beginning of each round increase it, and at the end of the round check the current round and make a if then logic.

```
Dim myRound as Integer = 0
```

And in the PlayForm in the constructor.

```
myRound += 1
```

Once the round is complete.

```
if myRound >= 3 Then
    'open the score page
Else
    'start the next round
End if
```

Comment: I've added those in because they're definitely what I needed, but that's also the bit I'm struggling with. Your comment 'Start the next round' is what I am stuck on. I've no idea how to restart a new round where all the buttons are clickable again and a new word is loaded in.

Comment: I use WPF and not an expert in win forms, but they should be simular. 'Dim newWindow as New FormName, newWindow.Show(), me.Close(). This will open the new instance of the window and close the current window.

Answer (score 0):

```
'In General Declarations:
Dim ButtonList As New List(Of Button)  'or Of Control if you have other types of controls
Dim HgmList As New List(Of PowerPacks.Shape)
Dim AnswerList As New List(Of Label)    

'In PlayForm_Load:
With ButtonList
    .Clear()
    .Add(Me.BtnA)
    .Add(Me.BtnB)
    .Add(Me.BtnC)
    'You get the idea
    'Add all your buttons you want to re-enable to the list
End With
With HgmList
    .Clear()
    .Add(Me.SideFrameLine)
    .Add(Me.TopFrameLine)
    .Add(Me.CornerFrameLine)
    'etc.
End With
With AnswerList
    .Add(Me.FirstLetterLbl)
    'etc. Just like the other two.
End With

'At the end of your `If Correct = False Then` Block:
Else  'Check for win after each correct guess
    Dim Winner As Boolean = True
    Dim CheckLetter As Label
    For Each CheckLetter in AnswerList
        If Not CheckLetter.Visible Then
            Winner = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Winner Then
        NextRound(10)
    End If
End If

'Somewhere inside your form code:
Private Sub NextRound(RoundScore As Integer)
    UserScore += RoundScore
    If TurnNumber = 3 Then 'Game Over
        MsgBox("Game Over" & vbNewLine & "Score: " & UserScore)
    Else 'This is the part you asked about: resetting the form
        TurnNumber += 1
        PlayForm_Load(Nothing, Nothing)
        Dim ResetControl As Control
        Dim ResetShape As PowerPacks.Shape
        For Each ResetControl In ButtonList
            ResetControl.Enabled = True
        Next
        For Each ResetShape In HgmList
            ResetControl.Visible = False
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I only added the .Clear() to the list builders because you already have your code to get a new word in PlayForm_Load. If you move it (say to a new Sub called NewWord), you don't need .Clear, and you would call your new sub instead of PlayForm_Load.

Comment: I used TurnNumber because I thought that was how you were counting rounds. (I didn't see you using it above; if you are trying to limit the number of turns per round, you need to incriment TurnNumber at the end of AllBtnCLicks and check to see if the player has used all his turns.) You can replace TurnNumber with myRound if I misunderstood its meaning.

Comment: This actually looks very promising, let me give it a try!

Comment: Okay just a few things that it doesn't like: Winner and AnswerList are undeclared and it also says: HgmList value of type Microsoft.VisualBasic.Powerpacks.Shape cannot be converted to type System.Windows.Form.Control (This is probably because all the lines I am using for the hangman frame and body are lines from powerpack, not actual controls)

Comment: Okay nevermind, I fixed the 'Winner' bit. Now it just doesn't like 'AnswerList' and 'HgmList'. I tried changing 'HgmList As New List(Of PowerPacks.Shape) and that's what happened. If I do it your way and make it control, the list of 'Me.Add(SideFrameLine) etc becomes underlined in blue.

Comment: And yes, A turn is basically a round.

Comment: Did changing the list to your Shape type work? Anything not working?

Comment: I changed HgmList As New List(OfControl) to HgmList As New List(Of PowerPacks.Shape) which caused all blue lines on the Me.Add(SideFrameLine) etc etc to go away. But, it creates a blue line on HgmList in the ResetControl bit. Also, AnswerList isn't declared

Comment: We're close I can feel it, I just need to fix these two bits

Comment: Sorry. I deleted AnswerList because I didn't end up needing it to reset the answer letters when I realized you already had that code in PlayForm_Load and forgot that I'd used it elsewhere. Declare it with the other lists `Dim AnswerList As New List(Of Label)` and add FirstLetterLbl etc. to it during PlayForm_Load (just like the other two lists). Declare `Dim ResetShape As PowerPacks.Shape` right under ResetControl and make it `For Each ResetShape In HgmList`

Comment: Should I move this to chat? it's telling me to avoid long discussions. Also, it appears to work! the form resets after each word whether it's right or wrong! but, I have a problem. Now, whenever I get a letter wrong, it seems to be displaying the hangman in the wrong order. (eg. it displays a floating torso rather than the corner of the hangman scaffold)     However, on the first turn it's correct. The hangman works in the right order. On the next turns, it's all not in order.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me by the way! it's almost done!

Comment: Okay, so I did some fiddling around, and now this problem only happens on the 3rd and Final turn.

Comment: NEVERMIND! I GOT IT TO WORK!

Comment: Good job. Happy to help.

Comment: I can't chat with you unfortunately. But seriously, thanks so much for your help, this actually helped me complete my assignment which I was worrying and getting stressed about. Is there anyway I can pay you for your help? through PayPal or something? I'm just a student, but I really want to show my appreciation, thank you so much.

Comment: I appreciate the thought but don't worry about it. Pay it forward. Help someone who needs it when you can. I've been on your side of a dead end plenty of times myself. Since this was an assignment, if you want to chat about why the solution works or general questions, my email is in my profile.